# Convolutional filter applied to Fourier-transformed signal

Tags: deep-learning, filtering, fft, convolution

I understand that the Fourier transform of a convolution of two signals is the pointwise product of their Fourier transforms ([convolutional theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)). What I wonder is there known cases where a convolution can be meaningfully applied to a Fourier-transformed signal (e.g. time series, or image) in the frequency domain to act as a filter instead of the multiplication by a square matrix. Also, are there known applications of filters that increase the size of the time domain, ie where the matrix in the frequency domain is rectangular, and then an inverse FT is applied to back to the time domain? In particular, I'm interested known examples of such method for deep learning.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, convolution of two signals is the pointwise product of their Fourier transforms. This is true in both directions - the convolution of two Fourier-transformed signals is equal to the pointwise product of the two time series.

You do have to define "convolution" suitably - for discrete Fourier transforms, the convolution is a circular convolution.

There are definitely meaningful uses for doing a pointwise block multiply in the time domain (for example, applying a data window to a signal before converting to the frequency domain, or modulating a carrier), so you can say that it is meaningful to do the convolution in the frequency domain. But it is unlikely to be efficient, compared to just doing the operation in the time domain.

Note that a LOT of effort has been spent over the years at optimizing Fourier transforms, precisely because it is more efficient to do a block multiply in the frequency domain (it is O(n)) compared to doing a convolution in the time domain (which is O(n^2)). Since the Fourier transform is O(n log(n)), the combination of forwardTransform-blockMultiply-inverseTransform is usually faster than doing a convolution. This is still true in the other direction, so if you start with frequency data a inverseTransform-blockMultiply-forwardTransform will usually be faster than doing a convolution in the frequency domain. And, of course, usually you already have the original time data somewhere, so the block multiply in the time domain would then be even faster.

Unfortunately, I don't know of applications that increase the size of the time domain off the top of my head. And I don't know anything about deep learning, so I can't help you there.